# Error in transferring .txt file to Array (Thread Exception)

Tags: java, arrays, text-files

I'm trying to transfer a text file that states "It was a bright cold day in April, and the clocks were striking thirteen," To a two-dimensional array. It should fill any unused spaces in the 2-D array with the ‘*’ character. But when I run this program I get an error stating "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    at TwoDArray.main(TwoDArray.java:24)"
How do I fix this error?

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class TwoDArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("2DArray.txt");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        int totalRow = 6;
        int totalColumn = 7;
        char[][] chars = new char[totalRow][totalColumn];

            while (input.hasNext()) {
            String word = input.next();
            char[] words = word.toCharArray();
            int i = 0;
            for (int r = 0; r < words.length; r++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < totalColumn; c++) {
                    if (i < words.length) {
                        chars[r][c] = words[i] == ' ' ? '+' : words[i];
                        i++;
    } 
                    else {chars[r][c] = '*';
                    }
                }
            }
            for (char[] x : chars) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
         }
    }
    }   
    }
```

The error is:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   6 at TwoDArray.main(TwoDArray.java:24)"

Comment: I know the formatting isn't awesome but hopefully, it's readable.

Comment: might it be that you are declaring an array of 6 by 7, but are trying to get row 6 (where it only goes from 0 to 5) ? Arrays are zero based (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays)

Comment: This is java not C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not totally sure what you are doing here but shouldn't

```
        for (int r = 0; r < words.length; r++) {
```

be

```
        for (int r = 0; r < totalRow; r++) {
```

I expect that is that your problem.

Comment: That worked for me, thanks! Do you have any idea on how I can have the output have only one space between the words instead of the large amount asterisks (I am wanting only the one for the space, if at all.

Comment: @ZachGoniea Just change your code to skip a space if the prior was a space

Comment: do you think you could give me some pointers on how to do that, I'm new to this sorry.

Comment: @ZachGoniea I would do it like this 1) create a flag variable (called haddaspace) and set it to 0 -- when I have a space I would set to * if haddaspace was 0 and set haddaspace to 1 and if it isn't a space I would set haddaspace to 0.  All of this is in addition to what you are currently doing

Comment: so should the variable be a boolean or a char?

Comment: @ZachGoniea anything that can have two values.  probably boolean but integer works too.

Comment: How do I set the variable equal to space?

Comment: I'm sorry, obviously I misread your comment. I guess my real question is I don't fully understand how I identify (with the program) whether or not there is a space or a letter in the file.

Comment: if you don't want to help me anymore just let me know so I can stop checking! Thanks for the help you did give!

Comment: Firstly, thanks again for the info you've given me, I wouldn't have figured it out without your help. Could you maybe write out what the code would look like? Sorry, I'm a visual learner and I struggle with interpreting a written out version like you posted. There's nothing wrong with what you said, I'm sorry it came off as passive aggressive.

Comment: @ZachGoniea https://gist.github.com/hoganlong/32b0ffad7843daee85b706fe8e329f96

Comment: Sorry, there was an error on my end, could it look like this? (7 letters/spaces to each line in the array for a total of 6 rows) so only 42 spaces.

Comment: also I've discovered that the words don't have to all fit in the array which is infuriating of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TwoDArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("2DArray.txt");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        int totalRow = 6;
        int totalColumn = 7;
        char[][] chars = new char[totalRow][totalColumn];

            while (input.hasNext()) {
            String word = input.next();
            char[] words = word.toCharArray();
            int i = 0;
            for (int r = 0; r < words.length; r++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < totalColumn; c++) {
                    if (i < words.length) {
                        chars[r][c] = words[i] == ' ' ? '+' : words[i];
                        i++;
    } // I dont see what text you putting in the buffer, but try get i back to zero like:
       i = 0;

                    else {chars[r][c] = '*';
                    }
                }
            }
            for (char[] x : chars) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
         }
    }
    }   
    }
```